# Compare two known Complex type object without using reflection

Tags: c#

I have two known Complex Object of same type or even two object of two different class having exactly same properties.
How can I compare properties of the two object WITHOUT using reflection or manual properties comparison.?

Comment: What is the problem using reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, you can't... Unless the objects already implement an `Equals` method :-) There are no magic fairies that will compare objects in .NET .

Technically there is a third way... It goes totally against what you literally wrote, but is normally considered to be "acceptable": write a T4 template that, using reflection, generates a .cs file containing the comparator (that compares the objects using manual property comparison). The T4 is run at compile time, and the .cs generated is generated at compile time (and compiled), so there is no reflection at runtime, and there is no "human written" manual property comparison.

**Note that doing this T4 template correctly is very complex... It is a project inside a project!**
There are many ways to do it, each one with its pitfalls. Just deciding what to compare (fields or properties) is a problem enough. And for the fields/properties, do you want to compare everything with an option to exclude something, or nothing with an option to include what you really want to compare? Then deciding what to do with collections (do you want to compare their elements?). Many decisions to take!

Comment: With regards to .Equals implementation - even the default equality comparer uses reflection under the hood.

Comment: @series0ne For `struct` types, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Correct, for struct types. I believe the default equality comparer for classes just compares their reference

Comment: @series0ne About reflection and `struct` types: It is like the quote from Nixon: *If the President Does It, That Means It’s Not Illegal*... When .NET does it, it is not reflection, it is .NET magic :-) ([only trusted code can normally use reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: What if we wanted to check, if two different object having exactly the same properties differ with any values: Ex: 

            Employee1 emp1 = new Employee1()
            emp1.id = 1;
            emp1.name = "sharad";

            Employee2 emp2 = new Employee2()
            emp2.id = 1;
            emp2.name = "rahul";

Answer (score 1):

As xanatos says above, you cannot, however there are a [bunch of widgets](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=object%20comparison) which have done this for you.

For example: https://github.com/StevenGilligan/AutoCompare

Comment: Obviously `AutoCompare` uses reflection (plus `Expression` trees from its description)

Comment: @xanatos yes I acknowledge this does not directly address the question.